# Server-sided DataTable rows count function returns only the total number of the current page

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I have the following datatable that is set to server side mode:

[image]

As you can see on footer, the total of rows is 21.

But, when I call the function that should return the total of rows, it only returns 10, that is the total of the current page:

[image]

How to make it returns 21 instead of 10?

---

Here's the client-side code of the datatable:

```
tableOcorrenciaAgendadosHoje = $('#tableOcorrenciaAgendadosHoje').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: "/Ocorrencia/GetOcorrencias",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        data: function (d) {
            d.aba = "agendadosHoje";
        }
    },
    aoColumnDefs: [{
        orderable: false, aTargets: [0]
    }],
    order: [],
    columns: colunas,
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    fixedColumns: {
        leftColumns: 2,
    },
    language: {
        url: "/Content/js/Portuguese-Brasil.json"
    },
    serverSide: "true",
    processing: "true",
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I simply added the following function to the datatable:

```
fnDrawCallback: function () {
    self.QtdOcorrenciasAgendadosHoje = this.api().page.info().recordsTotal;
}
```

It always returns the total of records, even when the table is updated.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info()

The following should work in your case:
`$(table_id).DataTable().page.info().recordsTotal`